# Data values read from txt.file into 2D array are getting flipped

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I need to mark the beginning of a maze by the string value at position [0][0] in a 2D array. The problem is that every time it reads a new line the value at position [i][0] can change and I need it to always be the very first value at position[0][0]. There are no spaces or delimiters so I am reading each char value in each row in each line.

I can't figure out how to get it just see that the string at maze[0][0] is the string I want to set to 1?

The maze is laid out so that the first row has 2 integers; 1st int=#of rows in the maze, 2nd int=#of columns in the maze. the start is always [0][0] and the end is always [row-1][col-1]. The remaining rows are the maze. So line 2 in the text file = row 0 of the maze.

So I read the the file as String values and then parsed the 1st line String values into int's and used those values to define my 2D array of integers.

then I read through the remaining lines and compared them to the very first char value which is always  equal to the values that make up the path if it exists. If the symbol read is = to the path then it is stored as a 1, else it is stored as a 0. I am then going to go through the 2D array and start comparing the different coordinates to determine the path and store that info in a Queue and then a Stack.

the problem I'm having is that it works for the first 3 rows, but the values 1 & 0 get flipped for the remaining rows. I have attached the snipit of code, the .txt file it is reading from. I know it is because it is comparing itself to the first element of each row and for the first 3 rows it is a "." and then a "+" for the remaining rows.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MazeArray {
    String info;
    String[] rowCol;
    //private char [][] maze;
    private int [][] maze; 
    private Scanner readFile;
    private int path, cur, row, col; 

public MazeArray()


{
    maze = new int[0][0];
}

public int[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException
{
    readFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); 

    info = readFile.nextLine();
    rowCol = info.split(" ",2);
    row = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[0]);
    col = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[1]);
    maze = new int[row][col];
    System.out.println("# of rows: " + row + " # of col: " + col);

    while (readFile.hasNextLine())
    {
        //System.out.println(readFile.next()); 

        for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            String symbol = readFile.nextLine();

            for (int j=0; j<col; j++)
            {
                path = symbol.charAt(0);
                //safe = symbol.charAt(maze[0][0]);
                maze[i][j] = symbol.charAt(j);
                if (maze[i][j] == path)
                {
                    maze[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    maze[i][j] = 0;
                }
                System.out.println("for loop Path coord = (" + i + " , " + j + ") Value at coord = " + maze[i][j]);

            }//for j      
        }//for i
    }// while
    readFile.close();
    return maze;
}
```

**Contents of txt.File (Maze)**

```
7 12
..+.+.++++++
.++...++...+
..++.....+.+
+.+..++.+..+
+...++....++
+.+++..++..+
++++++++++..
```

**Output - RIGHT**

```
for loop Path coord = (0 , 0) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (0 , 1) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (0 , 2) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 3) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (0 , 4) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 5) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (0 , 6) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 7) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 8) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 9) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 10) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (0 , 11) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (1 , 0) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 1) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (1 , 2) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (1 , 3) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 4) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 5) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 6) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (1 , 7) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (1 , 8) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 9) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 10) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (1 , 11) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (2 , 0) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 1) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 2) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (2 , 3) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (2 , 4) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 5) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 6) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 7) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 8) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 9) Value at coord = 0
for loop Path coord = (2 , 10) Value at coord = 1
for loop Path coord = (2 , 11) Value at coord = 0
```

**Output - WRONG**

```
for loop Path coord = (3 , 0) Value at coord = 1 //Value should = 0 because ="+"
for loop Path coord = (3 , 1) Value at coord = 0
```

Comment: could you post the content of file you are using?

Comment: The Maze section is the contents of the file.

Comment: I renamed it to Contents of File to make it easier. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is within the inner `for` loop:

```
path = symbol.charAt(0); // <-- this is erroneous
maze[i][j] = symbol.charAt(j);
if (maze[i][j] == path) {
  maze[i][j] = 1;
} else {
  maze[i][j] = 0;
}
```

You are changing the `path` field for every row. So for the first three rows, you are setting path to `.` because this is the first char in the row. On the fourth row, the first char is  `+` so the results appear flipped.

You need to decide how to determine the path character and do it only once, per file. If you are confident that the first character in the entire maze is the path symbol, then read that once and store it:

```
public int[][] readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
  readFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

  info = readFile.nextLine();
  rowCol = info.split(" ", 2);
  row = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[0]);
  col = Integer.parseInt(rowCol[1]);
  maze = new int[row][col];
  System.out.println("# of rows: " + row + " # of col: " + col);

  int row = 0;

  while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String symbol = readFile.nextLine();

    if (row == 0) {
      path = symbol.charAt(0);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      maze[row][j] = symbol.charAt(j);
      if (maze[row][j] == path) {
        maze[row][j] = 1;
      } else {
        maze[row][j] = 0;
      }
      System.out.println("Path coord = (" + row + " , " + j
          + ") Value at coord = " + maze[row][j]);

    }// for j

    row++;

  }// while
  readFile.close();
  return maze;
}
```

I have also corrected your looping structure. In your original example, your `while` loop was ineffective and only looped once. Your `for` loop was doing all the work (without checking there were lines to read).

Other observations:

- Currently your class could be simplified to a utility class with a single static method (although I appreciate this may change in the future).
- You have temporary variables (e.g. `row`, `col` and `readFile`) stored as fields in your class; they should instead be variables in your method.
- You appear to be storing binary values (`1` and `0`) in an array, but as integers. You could consider instead returning a boolean array.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to explain. These changes worked and I will look into switching the array to booleans vs. integers.

Comment: I stored the row, col and readfile as fields in my class go I can access them from other classes. But I will leave out read file because it doesn't make sense.